# Do I need use the same version of iperf3 in client and server?

Tags: testing, tcp, iperf, iperf3

I was testing our equipment TCP performance using iperf3, WiFi, powerline and ethernet. Do I need use the same version in both client and server so that I won't see weird issue or performance drop?

Current I'm using
server: iperf 3.1.3
client: iperf 3.0.11

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

For the most part you can use different versions of iperf3 between the client and server.  Clearly they'll only be able to use features / functionality that the client and server have in common.

There were some old "beta" versions of iperf3 that weren't compatible with later versions, but everything since the official 3.0 release should interoperate with everything else.  If not, I'd consider that a bug.